# How to package up test and normal implementations of a class

Tags: oop, architecture

I am not quite sure if this question is relevant here; maybe it's too high level.

Say I have an interface `Foo` which is implemented by two other concrete classes `FooProduction` and `FooTest`. The first one is the production code and the other one the test implementation. Now I want to package everything up but I am not sure which is more suitable. Moving the `FooTest` class in the test package (where I keep all my tests) or keeping `Foo`, `FooProduction` and `FooTest` in the another package, lets say the foo package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that making sure `FooTest` can *never* find it's way onto a production machine would be the highest priority. As such my vote would be for dividing things along the `Test`/`Production` boundary.

I don't know what language you're actually implementing, but in the Java world, the [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) software management system is extremely popular and generally well-regarded, and it makes extremely strong distinctions between so-called "`main`" and "`test`" code, resource files, and dependencies. Indeed in their documentation they indicate this is a ["testing best practice"](http://maven.apache.org/what-is-maven.html#Providing_guidelines_for_best_practices_development).

As to where to put the interface `Foo` and its `FooProduction` implementation, that's really a question of personal (or site) preference. I like having a package that holds all the domain model objects together for example.

Answer (score 1):

`FooTest` should be in a separate package than the production code
Whether or not `IFoo` and `FooProduction` should go on the same package or on two separate ones depends on the variability  of `FooProduction` (how many implementations are you looking for in the future)